# uniformly convergence on complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f_n$ is analytic in a domain $D \subset\mathbb{C}$ and $f_n$ converges to a function $f$ uniformly on each compact subset of $D$.
Problem) 1. $f$ is analytic in $D$ and  2.$f'_n$ converges uniformly to $f'$ on each compact subset of $D$.

I tried to solve problem 1 using Morera's theorem, but it concludes that $f$ is analytic in each compact subset of $D$, NOT whole $D$.
How can I show that $f$ is analytic in whole $D$?

Comment: $D$ is a domain, so it's an open set. If $f$ is analytic on each compact subset of $D$, then in particular $f$ is analytic on each closed disk contained in $D$. So $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood of each point in $D$. By definition, *that's all you need* to conclude that $f$ is analytic in $D$.

Comment: @bof you mean that it is sufficient by choosing a neighborhood contained in a close disk, which is also contained in D??

Comment: @JeongNam-ho Yes, this is the way to go.

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analyticity is a *local property*, which means the following: if every point of   $D$ has a neighborhood in which $f$ has the property, then $f$ has the property in $D$.

- Some other local properties: continuity, differentiability, being $C^k$ smooth
- Some non-local properties: being bounded, being integrable.

Every point $z\in D$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that $\overline{U}\subset D$. Uniform convergence in $\overline{U}$ allows you to use Morera's theorem and conclude that $f$ is analytic in $U$.